# How do I map data from mongoose database in embeds (discord.js)

Tags: mongodb, discord.js

**Question**

The code below maps data from database in [`MessageEmbed.description`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed?scrollTo=description). I want to map each data in [**`MessageEmbed.fields`**](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed?scrollTo=fields). I tried using `for()` loop but I want a brief idea on how to do that since I'm using 2 listeners:- **w** (content of data) and **i** (position of data in db).

**My Code**

```
await db.findOne({ guildid: message.guild.id, user: member.user.id }, async(err, data) =>{
            if(err) throw err;
            if(data) {
                
                const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                    .setTitle(`${message.author.tag}`)
                    .setDescription(
                        data.content.map(
                            (w, i) => 
                            `\`${i + 1}\` | **${w.data1}**\n**${w.data2}**`
                        )
                    )                   
                    .setFooter(`Total : ${data.content.length}`)
                    
                message.channel.send(embed)
            } else {
                message.channel.send('No data found')
            }
        });
```

**for() loop [My attempt]**

```
for(w, i of data.content){
   embed.addField(`${i + 1}`, `${w.data1}\n${w.data2}`, true)
};
```

However, this resulted in an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `.forEach()` which will yield the current element as well as the current index:

```js
data.content.forEach((w, i) => {
    embed.addField(`${i + 1}`, `${w.data1}\n${w.data2}`, true);
});
```

If you want to stick with a `for` loop, use `for .. in` to get the index:

```js
for (let i in data.content){
   let w = data.content[i];
   embed.addField(`${i + 1}`, `${w.data1}\n${w.data2}`, true);
}
```

I wouldn't recommend the latter though.

Comment: The second is actually better since you can use a `break` statement much easier than `forEach`.

Comment: Yes, Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @DarshanB No problem! Glad I could help :)

Comment: Also, the `forEach()` method is more efficient in my case.

Comment: I wanted to limit it to 25 fields and the rest using **[pagination](https://www.npmjs.com/package/discord.js-pagination)**, is there anyway I can do it?

Comment: @DarshanB unfortunately I've never worked with pagination. I guess your best bet is to post that as a new/different question

Comment: I'll try it myself at first, and if I face any error, I'll post it as a question